# Using single quotes with echo in bash

Tags: bash, command-line

I am running some code from the command line by using echo and piping. 
This is the line of code I am trying to run:

```
echo 'import Cocoa;println("It's over there")' | xcrun swift -i -v -
```

I tried using a backslash to escape the single quote with a backslash like so:

```
echo 'import Cocoa;println("It\'s over there")' | xcrun swift -i -v -
```

That does not work. 
I have seen other questions about using single quotes in bash but they seem to have the single quote as part of the script. In my case the single quote is part of some string that is being passed in from the echo. I don't really understand how to pass this particular string into bash without causing the following error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

This is probably very simple, and I am just being dumb but after searching for a while I cannot seem to figure out how to do this for my particular situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you unsure about the quotes, just use the bash's `heredoc` feature:

```
cat <<'SWIFT' | xcrun swift -i -v -
import Cocoa;println("It's over there")
SWIFT
```

And if you use it unquoted e.g. `SWIFT` instead of `'SWIFT'` you can use bash variables inside.

The best is use it as an function, like

```
getcode() {
cat <<SWIFT
import Cocoa;println("It's over there $1")
SWIFT
}

getcode "now" | xcrun swift -i -v -
```

will send to xcrun the text

```
import Cocoa;println("It's over there now")
```

Answer (score 4):

In BASH you cannot use nested single quote OR escape the single quote. But you can escape double quotes like this:

```
echo "import Cocoa;println(\"It's over there\")"
import Cocoa;println("It's over there")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
echo 'import Cocoa;println("It'\''s over there")'
```

Which gives:

```
import Cocoa;println("It's over there")
```

Remember, in the bourne shell, `echo` will output the entire line, and a quote is just a "start interpreting this as literal" and "stop interpreting this as a literal" marker, which is slightly different from most programming languages.

Also see [the POSIX spec of `/bin/sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02)

Comment: So you are quoting the backslash?

Comment: @Johnston No, this stops quoting the string, outputs a `'`, and starts quoting again.

Comment: aha I see. There are more than one way to do this apparently.

Comment: @Johnston Yes :) All proposed solutions are standard-compliant and "good". Some might prefer one over the other for reasons of readability or whatever, but it's really a personal choice.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
echo -e 'Here you\x27re'
```

or

```
echo "Here you're"
```

Comment: You need to use `echo -e "\x27"`

Comment: @Carpetsmoker oops, you are right, I tested with ZSH.... I am gonna add the `-e`, zsh makes me even more lazy...

Comment: why `-e`? Do I need to use `\x27re` or `\x27`

Comment: @Johnston `-e` enables parsing of special characters inside the `echo` string; this is not needed for `tcsh` and `zsh`, only `bash` and `sh`; `\x27re` is just `'re`.

Comment: @Johnston `re is just abbrev. for 're (are)`, the single quote is `\x27`. give it a try, you will see. why `-e`, read man echo

Answer (score 0):

Since single-quotes can go "plainly" in double-quoted strings, I usually do something like this:

```
echo 'import Cocoa;println("It'"'"'s over there")' | xcrun swift -i -v -
```

I.e. end the single-quoted string, start a double-quoted string containing just a single-quote, end the double-quoted and start a new single-quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else has mentioned it, you can use an ANSI-quoted string in `bash`, which can contain an escaped single quote. (Note the `$` preceding the single-quoted string.)

```
echo $'import Cocoa;println("It\'s over there")' | xcrun swift -i -v -
```