# Single quotes within single quotes issue - Bash command line GNU parallel

Tags: regex, bash, command-line, quotes, gnu-parallel

I am new to Bash command line use, and need to know the correct syntax for doing single quotes within existing single quotes.

```
ls *file.fa | parallel -j4 'perl -pe 's/^>/>{}/' {} >newfile_{}'
```

I know the GNU parallel command is not particularly well known or used but i don't think the syntax would be different for a different command that requires single quotes within single quotes. The command is to change > to >file.fa (> then the file name) within the file called file.fa, where {} incorporates the file piped from the ls *file.fa section.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: try `'perl -pe "s/^>/>{}/" {} >newfile_{}'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using single quotes with echo in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608503/using-single-quotes-with-echo-in-bash)

Comment: Single quotes don't nest. The single quotes that start your `sed` command are actually closing the string that starts at `'perl`, etc. Either swap quotes like @AvinashRaj suggested or use `'\''` to "escape" the internal single quotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot - substituting one pair of single quotes for a double quotes works

Comment: It's also worth noting that modern GNU xargs (with `-P`) has enough functionality to often make the mess that is GNU parallel unnecessary.

Comment: ...also, using `ls` in a pipeline is inherently broken in and of itself; `printf '%s\n' *file.fa` is a less-broken equivalent that generates a newline-delimited list, or `printf '%s\0' *file.fa` a not-broken-at-all (if `nullglob` is set) equivalent that generates a NUL-delimited list (which `xargs` or `parallel` can accept with appropriate option flags). See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy if you want to go down that road, then this is often shorter: `parallel ... ::: *.fa`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting in GNU Parallel is a black art. There is [a whole section dedicated to quoting in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#quoting).

> **Conclusion:** To avoid dealing with the quoting problems it may be easier just to write a small script or a function (remember to export -f the function) and have GNU **parallel** call that.

In this case I would write a function:

```
fasta_namer() {
  NAME=$1
  perl -pe "s/^>/>$NAME/" "$NAME" >newfile_"$NAME"
}
export -t fasta_namer
ls *file.fa | parallel -j4 fasta_namer {}
```

FASTA file names are usually not weird, but if they are (e.g. containing ' " \ * & / or other crazy chars) then this might solve it:

```
fasta_namer() {
  NAME=$1
  PERLQUOTED=$2
  NEWNAME=$3
  perl -pe "s/^>/>$PERLQUOTED/" "$NAME" >"$NEWNAME"
}
export -t fasta_namer
ls *file.fa | parallel -j4 fasta_namer {} '{=$_=quotemeta($_)=}' {.}.new.fa
```